# Why isn't there an Optional.or(Optional default) method?

Tags: java, guava, option-type

Is there a way to make the following code sample more concise?

```
final FluentIterable<AuthContext> withEmails = // ...               
final Optional<AuthContext> verified = withEmails.firstMatch(VERIFIED_EMAIL);

if (verified.isPresent()) {
    return verified.get();
}

return withEmails.first().orNull();
```

I was trying to do something like `return verified.or(withEmails.first())` but there is no appropriate method in [`Optional`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html).

Alternatively `return verified.or(withEmails.first().orNull())` will fail when the `orNull()` method returns null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do `verified.or(withEmails.first()).orNull();`.

Depending on the return type of your method and your IDE of choice, the type inference may not suggest this as it returns another `Optional` of type T rather an a T itself.

c.f. [Optional#or(Optional)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#or%28com.google.common.base.Optional%29)

Comment: It's tagged with `guava`, so I referenced those docs -- though I also see that `withEmails` is a list of concrete, not Optional AuthContexts, so this actually isn't correct.

Comment: yeah saw that too just was confused since the method was clearly present in the interface but is missing in the Java 8 version.

Comment: All right, I checked `FluentIterable`'s Javadocs and `first()` **does** return an `Optional` -- so I'm leaving my answer standing for now unless OP can clear up why the `or` method isn't working for them (old library?)

Comment: @LeonardBrünings FYI, they renamed most of the Optional methods -- it's `orElse` in JDK8

Comment: yes there is `orElse` but it only accepts `T` and not `Optional<T>` so chaining Optionals is not possible with Java8 Optional.

Comment: True, but then I would do `optional.or(() -> other.orNull());` using a lambda for the `Supplier` instance.

Comment: That's embarassing. I wasn't seeing this in intellisense because the expected return type was T not Optional<T>. Please note this in the anwser and I will accept it.